# An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to Linux. I suppose to run the Ruby project locally with older version of ruby(i.e., 2.0.0). When I run bundle install getting below error.

**An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before
bundling.**

I tried **gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'** still the issue remains same. Please help me with the solutions, I tried few commands from online with no luck.